# Request dialog -allowing user to select the friends to whom he has to send invite

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm using javascript request dialog to send app invite to friends.

when i send invite to b, I should not be able to send invitation to him again.
Is there any way to show only friends to whom I've not sent invite in request dialog or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you're using [this function](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/), there's to things that can help you :

- The parameter **filters**, which you can turn to **app_non_users** for example, allowing you to invite only people who are not using your application. You can also pass a custom filter with all the *facebook ids* of people you can invite.
- And, maybe more useful for what you need, the parameter **exclude_ids** to which you can pass the array of IDs you don't want to be able to send requests. 
  So, when you send requests, you store information about it, like *facebook ids* of the people you sent it to, then you just pass a list of these ids to your function.

But, keep in mind that someone can decline your request, and nothing is sent to you, you have to check it yourself !